# Python SQLAlchemy - How to update database using object within model by a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am writing a simple login which has one time passwords using the PyOTP library and SQLalchemy and a class I am using which works fine.

I want to save the current TOTP into the database once validated using this:

```
session = Session()
self.lastOtp = currentTotp
session.commit()
session.close()
```

But it doesn't update the database at all. I think it's because the method doesn't know it's the specific user object I am trying to update but I've tried adding self to various lines to figure it out but cannot.  I've the following working:

```
methodSession = Session()
currentUser = methodSession.query(User).filter_by(emailAddress=self.emailAddress).one()
currentUser.lastOtp = currentTotp
methodSession.commit()
methodSession.close()
self.lastOtp = currentTotp
```

But that means another database query and I already have a User object which I can access as self.

This is the full user class

```
# user class
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstName = Column(String(64))
    lastName = Column(String(64))
    emailAddress = Column(String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    passwordHash = Column(String(128))
    secretKey = Column(BLOB)
    lastOtp = Column(String(128))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.emailAddress)

    def set_password(self, password):
        # function to set password hash
        self.passwordHash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        # function to check password returning true or false
        return check_password_hash(self.passwordHash, password)

    def set_secret_key(self):
        # function to set the secure secret key
        pass

    def get_secret_key(self):
        # function to return the secure secret key
        pass
        
    def check_secret_key(self, secret_key):
        # function to check the otp returning true or false
        totp = pyotp.TOTP(self.get_secret_key())
        currentTotp = totp.now()
        if self.lastOtp == currentTotp:
            return False
        if totp.verify(secret_key):
            session = Session()
            self.lastOtp = currentTotp
            session.commit()
            session.close()
            return True
        return False
```

Expected behaviour:

```
session = Session()
myUser = session.query(User).filter_by(emailAddress='john@smith.com').one()
print("Last OTP: ", myUser.lastOtp)
>>> 987568
myUser.check_secret_key('123456')
>>> True
print("Last OTP: ", myUser.lastOtp)
>>> 123456
myUser.check_secret_key('123456')
>>> False
```

Comment: Is your `User` object already associated with  a session (that is, you got it by querying the db)?

Comment: Yep, I already have a session which I have queried like this myUser = session.query(User).filter_by(emailAddress='john@smith.com').one() when I run a myUser.check_secret_key('123456') if it's correct, the expected behaviour is to return True AND update the john@smith.com user's lastOtp both in the current object and to the database as 123456 so if 123456 is used again it will return False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `User` instance is already associated with a session, that session may be retrieved using [Session.object_session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.object_session):

```
def check_secret_key(self, secret_key):
    # function to check the otp returning true or false
    totp = pyotp.TOTP(self.get_secret_key())
    currentTotp = totp.now()
    if self.lastOtp == currentTotp:
        return False
    if totp.verify(secret_key):
        session = Session.object_session(self)
        self.lastOtp = currentTotp
        session.commit()
        return True
    return False
```

Note that committing this session will commit any other changes already associated with it.

Comment: Thanks man - that worked after a couple of tweaks outside the function.. :-)  really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the object you want to save to the SQLAlchemy session. I do not see in your code where you are doing that.
Specifically, here:

```
if totp.verify(secret_key):
            session = Session()
            self.lastOtp = currentTotp
            session.commit()
            session.close()
            return True
```

you are creating the Session, then commit and close it, without adding an instance of the object you want to save to it. You are missing a session.add(...) call.

Comment: I've updated the question.  I know I can add a complete new query (example code now included) and save but I already have the user object, there is already a database connection open and I have already updated the self.lastOtp.  How do I update the database, .add is not relevant here as I am updating.

Comment: Even if you updated the same instance before, the new Session you are creating in check_secret_key is not aware of the object you are trying to save. You have to attach the object to the Session you are creating before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Matei's comment means this is the only solution:

```
def check_secret_key(self, secret_key):
    # function to check the otp returning true or false
    totp = pyotp.TOTP(self.get_secret_key())
    currentTotp = totp.now()
    if self.lastOtp == currentTotp:
        return False
    if totp.verify(secret_key):
        methodSession = Session()
        currentUser = methodSession.query(User).filter_by(emailAddress=self.emailAddress).one()
        currentUser.lastOtp = currentTotp
        methodSession.commit()
        methodSession.close()
        self.lastOtp = currentTotp
        return True
    return False
```